# Retrofit/Gson how to create type adapters dynamically

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I learned from one example, so I am not sure if this is the optimal way or not, but anyways, I use the following code. I create one Retrofit instance and use it for all requests.

Since there are many methods, there are many types of data. It seems that I can create adapters (json -> my data class) automatically simply by adding annotations. But I needed more control (inheritance: the data classes have shared fields, dependency: some fields may not exist depending on other field's values), so I created a custom adaptor for each of the classes. So, currently my code is like this:

```
if (instance == null)
{
   val gson = GsonBuilder()
             .registerTypeAdapter(myClass1::class.java, myClassDeserialiser1())
              .... (tens of this) ....
             .registerTypeAdapter(myClass30::class.java, myClassDeserialiser30())
             .create()
    instance = Retrofit.Builder().
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                   .build()
                   .create(MyAPIs::class.java);
} 
return instance
```

The problem above is that I am creating instances of all parsers at the same time in advance. This may be inefficient. I wish I could create them when they are first needed. Is that possible?

Comment: *This may be inefficient* - but is it? You have not tested it I guess. You're asking to fix a problem that might not even exist

Comment: You are right, I am sorry for that. I thought I might need to check how much memory and time it consumes to create all those instances at once, but I thought it did not look good anyway (I sometimes forgot to register it after creating a new deserialiser class), so I wondered if there was a better way. Such as instead of calling `registerTypeAdapter` for each class, adding an annotation to deserialiser classes so that it could be automatically used when deserialising the types as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [`@JsonAdapter`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) annotation to your class definition in lieu of calling `registerTypeAdapter`.  I can't comment on its efficiency, but it keeps the adapter info tied to the object instead of the creation of your `Gson` object, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: Probably I am asking too much, but I have been using `JsonDeserializer<T>` which gave a `JsonElement`. Your solution is using `TypeAdapter<T>` which gives me a `JsonReader`. So, I cannot use `JsonDeserializer<T>`  for this method, right? Because reading complex structure data from `JsonReader` is a lot harder than from `JsonElement`.

Comment: You can use `JsonParser` (https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) to transform it.  Allocate a `JsonParser` in your constructor to avoid reallocating it on each deserialization.   In your `read` method, do `JsonElement element = parser.parse(in)`  This gives up the efficiency of using `JsonReader`, but should be similar to `JsonDeserializer`