# How to properly make generic a usage of TypeAdapterFactory and TypeAdapter using Retrofit and Dagger2 in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

**Step by step,** I'll try to explain my situation, because I already wasted 2 days, but not getting the expected solution.

So, I'm not giving you any specific scenario, because use cases may change.

**Problem:** I want to use Gson TypeAdapterFactory and TypeAdapter using my existing structure which is implemented using MVVM, Retrofit and Dagger2.

**Notes:** I want to do for entire project so, TypeAdapterFactory and TypeAdapter should be generic type. Or let's say generic type approach is complicated, then how about handle different type of API responses?

**Example1:** For the same key, depending on use cases, JSONObject may come or JSONArray also. Please note the key which I'm talking about that may inside some nested data class.
**Example2:** A key is coming to double, but I want that in dataclass it should store as abc.toInt()

Like that there are many use cases are there in project, so I want to use TypeAdapterFactory and TypeAdapter.

**Please note:** I don't want to use JSONDeseriliazer, because that is old approach and few limitations.

**Code:**

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCartGsonConverterFactory(): GsonConverterFactory {
        val customGson: Gson = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(CartResponse::class.java, CustomTypeAdapter::class.java)
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(CustomTypeAdapterFactory())
            .create()

        return GsonConverterFactory.create(customGson)

    }
```

**CustomTypeAdapter:**

```
class CustomTypeAdapter<T> (val classOfT: Class<in T>) : TypeAdapter<T>() {
    private val gson: Gson = Gson()


      override fun write(jsonWriter: JsonWriter?,  value: T) {
          gson.toJson(classOfT, OfferItem::class.java, jsonWriter)
      }


    override fun read(jsonReader: JsonReader): T {
        val locations: T = null
        jsonReader.beginObject()
        jsonReader.nextName()
        if (jsonReader.peek() === JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
           /* locations = T(
                gson.fromJson(
                    jsonReader,
                    Array<T>::class.java
                ) as Array<Item?>
            )*/
        } else if (jsonReader.peek() === JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {

        } else {
            throw JsonParseException("Unexpected token " + jsonReader.peek())
        }
        jsonReader.endObject()
        return T
    }

}
```

**CustomTypeAdapterFactory:**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

class CustomTypeAdapterFactory : TypeAdapterFactory {
    override fun <T> create(gson: Gson?, type: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
        val rawType = type.rawType
        return if (!rawType.isEnum) null else CustomTypeAdapter(rawType)
    }
}
```

I think something like this? [Retrofit/Gson how to create type adapters dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728625/retrofit-gson-how-to-create-type-adapters-dynamically)

I appreciate all answers, let me know if I can explain you better.

Comment: Could you please reduce this question to one specific problem? Please also provide example JSON data and reduce your code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: A few points I noticed about your code: Your `CustomTypeAdapterFactory` only seem to handle enums; not sure if that is intended. Also a `TypeAdapterFactory` should normally only handle a specific set of classes, e.g. all classes which implement a specific interface. Your `CustomTypeAdapter.write` function does not write `value`. While `GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter` accepts `Object` as argument, it actually expects an instance of a type adapter; passing `CustomTypeAdapter::class.java` to it will throw an exception.